# My jQuery Ajax not working with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post data and receive response using jQuery Ajax Post and I am not sure why my code is not working.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#login').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://code.com/backend/test3',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {"username":"akllkkj","password":"kljjkjkl"},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.stack);
                    console.log(data.key);
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form autocomplete="off" class="ui fluid form segment" method="post">
    <div class="ui fluid form segment">
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Email/Username</label>
                <input placeholder="Email/Username" name="username" id="username" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" type="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="ui fluid submit button" name="dosubmit" value="Submit" id="login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And my `test3` page contains:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $arr = array(
        'stack'=>'overflow',
        'key'=>'value'
    );
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
$('#form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = $('#form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data
    }).done(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });
});
```

And on the php side of things, you may need something like this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Doesn't return any output for me. Here is what I tried. http://20p.mallaprojects.com/backend/test4

Comment: @lock if the php is contained in the file with your html, you will probably need to put `exit;` after `echo json_encode();`

Comment: @lock what does your php look like now?

Comment: I fixed the problem. test3 page is returning both html and json so it couldn't decode the values.

Comment: @lock if you were to put your php above all html (before the `<html>` tag), and then use `exit;` that would also work, since no html will be produced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80315/discussion-between-lock-and-mikolaj).

Comment: Good, that exit is removing all the next code but how to remove the code that's printed before json?

Comment: I ended up using ob_clean and exit. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#login').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://code.com/backend/test3.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {"username":"akllkkj","password":"kljjkjkl"},
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                         if(obj)
                         {
                           for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
                             console.log(obj[i].stack);
                             console.log(obj[i].key);
                           }
                        } else {
                            console.log("Empty Result");
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
             });
        });
<script>
```

And you test3.php script will be:

```
<?php
$arr=array();
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $arr[] = array(
        'stack'=>'overflow',
        'key'=>'value'
    );   
}
 echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Failed with error `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: I fixed the problem. test3 page is returning both html and json so it couldn't decode the values.